# how to run maven-antrun-plugin targets?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, pom.xml, maven-antrun-plugin

I don't want to mess up with maven failsafe plugin. Also I wanted something to copy properties files for me not interested in entire lifecycle. So, now I am using two plugins `maven-failsafe-plugin` to run regular `clean, verify` tasks and `maven-antrun-plugin` only and only to copy properties file before `maven-failsafe-plugin` starts.
Below POM works fine if you remove profiles, i.e. if I don't have `profiles` under `maven-antrun-plugin` then it copies properties files using below command
`mvn clean test verify -Dwebdriver.driver=chrome -Dcucumber.options="--tags @sanity" -e`

But if I create profiles then it doesn't copy

`mvn clean test -Pqa verify -Dwebdriver.driver=chrome -Dcucumber.options="--tags @sanity" -e`

How can I make profiles work here? Am I executing wrong command?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.demo.automation</groupId>
    <artifactId>serenity-automation-tests</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Serenity Cucumber and WebDriver</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <serenity.version>2.0.18</serenity.version>
        <serenity.cucumber.version>1.6.6</serenity.cucumber.version>
        <webdriver.driver>firefox</webdriver.driver>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>bintray</name>
            <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>bintray-plugins</name>
            <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-cucumber</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <profiles>
                                <profile>
                                    <id>qa</id>
                                    <target>
                                        <delete>
                                            <fileset dir="${project.build.outputDirectory}"
                                                includes="*.properties" />
                                        </delete>
                                        <echo>Using env.test.properties</echo>
                                        <copy file="src/main/resources/qa.properties"
                                            tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/env.properties" />
                                    </target>
                                </profile>
                                <profile>
                                    <id>stage</id>
                                    <target>
                                        <delete>
                                            <fileset dir="${project.build.outputDirectory}"
                                                includes="*.properties" />
                                        </delete>
                                        <echo>Using env.test.properties</echo>
                                        <copy file="src/main/resources/stage.properties"
                                            tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/env.properties" />
                                    </target>
                                </profile>
                                <profile>
                                    <id>prod</id>
                                    <target>
                                        <delete>
                                            <fileset dir="${project.build.outputDirectory}"
                                                includes="*.properties" />
                                        </delete>
                                        <echo>Using env.test.properties</echo>
                                        <copy file="src/main/resources/prod.properties"
                                            tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/env.properties" />
                                    </target>
                                </profile>
                            </profiles>
                        </configuration>
                        <!-- <goals> <goal>run</goal> </goals> -->
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <argLine>-Xmx512m</argLine>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <webdriver.driver>${webdriver.driver}</webdriver.driver>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${serenity.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>serenity-reports</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're defining your profiles in the wrong place. The correct place is directly under project:

```
<project>
    ...
    <profiles>
```

and then the plugin-configuration for that profile:

```
<project>
    ...
    <profiles>
    ...
      <build>
          <plugins>
             ....
```

That means you'll have to define the plugins mutliple times (per profile). The profile-information in configuration has to be removed.

Comment: We can't have if-else in POM, this would avoid a page lengthy `pom.xml`?

Comment: But you only have to wrap the antrun-plugin in profiles, the others can stay the way they are...